# Difference in contract instance in web3 and truffle test

Tags: web3js, truffle, truffle-test

When I'm working whit web3 I have something like:

```
 var abi = [...];
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,"0x86Fa049857E0209aa7D9e616F7eb3b3B78ECfdb0");
```

then I use something like:

```
myContract.methods.myMethod(123).call(....
```

In truffle test I have a contract instance in hand, and I use

```
instance.myMethod(123)
```

without the "methods" indirection, what is different from the two contract instances?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that Truffle injects [Web3.js 0.20](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3js-api-reference) into the test script, whereas you are working with Web3.js 1.0.

Web3.js is a whole lot different from Web3.js 0.20.

Comment: in this case, which is best to learn and use? latest Web3.js ?

Comment: I would say so, yes.